# Clean up incomplete/failed uploads google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We have a application that uploads backup to google cloud storage. Sometimes backup fails to upload copy completely. I am looking a way to cleanup incomplete/failed uploads. Is there any lifecycle policy like aws s3 to cleanup incomplete upload?

Answer (score 0):

There are Lifecycle Management [policies](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) that you can apply in Cloud Storage objects, but there is no way to distinguish an incomplete upload from an actual complete object.

However, for situations where your upload is prone to failures, you can use [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads) as shown in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads) along with a [retry strategy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/retry-strategy) such as an exponential backoff. You can also confirm it was uploaded correctly by using an [integrity check](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#integrity_checks) in the request.

When using resumable uploads, **only a completed resumable upload appears in your bucket**, so you won't end up with incomplete uploads, whether or not you decide to resume a failed or incomplete one.

Comment: Our application don't have retry functionality. It creates new execution id for every new backup and it upload new backup set to bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using resumable uploads?  If not, then don't worry, the data is simply discarded when the upload is interrupted.  If you are using a resumable upload (which is most likely the case), then don't worry, the upload ids (and their associated data) are discarded after a week:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads#resume-upload

AFAIK that "one week" parameter is not tunable.  You can manually delete incomplete resumable uploads too:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads#cancel-upload

Comment: Thanks @Coryan. Actually, in our application If backup job partially completed and failed/interrupted in between then after new execution of same job not resume upload to same object. Actually it creates new backup set objects(database object backup) to upload. so, how to identify and cancel/delete incomplete data?

The above mentioned doc say's for resumable upload session uri expire after one week. It does not clearly say's it discard data after one week. If its really discard after one week then we will have to incur cost for one week. Is there any way to get list of incomplete objects?

Comment: I am not a billing expert, if you have an account manager that would be a better person to answer that type of question (whether you incur any costs for incomplete uploads, presumably yes, but I would check).  I do not know of any way to find out if you have any pending uploads.  If you are not going to resume / retry then just do a regular upload (a single PUT or POST, without a resumable session), then the whole problem of cleaning up the sessions / partial uploads goes away, right?

Comment: @VinayakShinde did this information solve your issue? As you seem to not be using resumable uploads, this answer's information is valid, and so is the approach of using regular uploads that will be discarded if the upload fails. You can see other best practices for uploading to Cloud Storage [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#uploading)